# Angular assign objects in subscribe

Tags: angular

I am following a tutorial from [here](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4), but I am trying to adapt the heroes.component.ts class slightly by using 'card' instead of 'hero'. When I attempt to call `.subscribe()` I am getting

> ERROR in src/app/card/card.component.ts(12,19): error TS1109: Expression expected.

my version (note cardlist variable name change)

```
export class CardComponent implements OnInit {

  cardlist = Card[];    //-------LINE 12

   ....  
getCards(): void {
    this.cardService.getCards()     //--------LINE 19
        .subscribe(c => this.cardlist = c);
  }
}
```

Here is what I think is happening inside the getCards() function:

1. method `getCards()` declared with a return type of void
2. calls the cardService (imported at top of file) to use the `getCards()` method
3. calling `.subscribe()` to listen for changes to that data
4. this bit: `c => this.cardlist = c` says for every card `c` passed in from the service add it to `cardlist`

**Clearly I'm wrong about step 4. What did I do wrong?**

---

Working tutorial code (reproduced for convenience):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Hero } from '../hero';
import { HeroService } from '../hero.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {

  selectedHero: Hero;

  heroes: Hero[]; 

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getHeroes();
  }

  onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
    this.selectedHero = hero;
  }

  getHeroes(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes()
        .subscribe(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
  }
}
```

Comment: turns out it was a syntax error `cardlist = Card[];` should have been `cardlist: Card[];`

Answer (score 2):

You are missing few paranthesis, try it as follows,

```
   getHeroes(): void {
        this.heroService.getHeroes()
        .subscribe(resUserData => {
            this.heroes = resUserData
          });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export class CardComponent implements OnInit {

  cardlist = Card[];

   ....  
getCards(): void {
    this.cardService.getCards()
        .subscribe(c => { this.cardlist = c);
  });
}
```